# Class B inheriting (int) datatypes from class A, but not (string) datatypes

Tags: c++, oop

Class B inheriting (int) datatypes from class A, but not (string) datatypes

```
`#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
class A
{
protected:
    string name;
    string dob;
    int age;
    string email;
    int ph_no;
    int roll_no;
    string course;
public:

    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const A &student);
    friend istream & operator>>(istream &in, A &student);
};
ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const A &student)
{
        out<<"\n\n";
        out<<"\t\t\t\tStudent Details";
        out<<"\n___________________________________________________________________________\n";
        out<<"\n";
        out<<"\t\tName:          "<<student.name<<"\n";
        out<<"\t\tDate of Birth: "<<student.dob<<"\n";
        out<<"\t\tAge:           "<<student.age<<"\n";
        out<<"\t\tCourse:        "<<student.course<<"\n";
        out<<"\t\tRoll no:       "<<student.roll_no<<"\n";
        out<<"\t\tPhone no:      "<<student.ph_no<<"\n";
        out<<"\t\tEmail id:      "<<student.email<<"\n";
        out<<"\n____________________________________________________________________________\n";
        return out;

}

istream & operator>>(istream &in, A &student)
{
        cout<<"Enter the student's full name:                              ";
        getline(in>>ws,student.name);
        cout<<"\nEnter the student's date of birth (dd/mm/yyyy):           ";
        getline(in>>ws,student.dob);
        cout<<"\nEnter the student's age:                                  ";
        in>>student.age;
        cout<<"\nEnter the student's current course he/she is studying in: ";
        in>>student.course;
        cout<<"\nEnter the student's roll number (only integers allowed):  ";
        in>>student.roll_no;
        cout<<"\nEnter the student's email id:                             ";
        in>>student.email;
        cout<<"\nEnter the student's phone no:                             ";
        in>>student.ph_no;
        return in;
}


class B: protected A
{
public:
    double current_cgpa;
    vector<string> skills;
    map<string,int> competitions_experiences;

        friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const B &student);
        friend istream & operator>>(istream &in, B &student);

};

ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const B &student)
{

        out<<"\n\n";
        out<<"\t\t\t\tStudent Resume";
        out<<"\n================================================\n";
        out<<"\t\tName:          "<<student.name<<"\n";
        out<<"\t\tDate of Birth: "<<student.dob<<"\t"<<"Age:"<<student.age<<"\n";
        out<<"\t\tEmail: "<<student.email<<"\n";
        out<<"\t\tContact no: "<<student.ph_no<<"\n";
        out<<"\t\tCourse Studying in college: "<<student.course<<"\n";
        out<<"\t\tCurrent CGPA: "<<student.current_cgpa<<"\n";
        out<<"\t\tSkills: ";
        stringstream ss1;
        for(auto it=student.skills.begin();it!=student.skills.end();it++)
        {
            if(it!=student.skills.begin())
            {
                ss1<<" ";
            }
            ss1<<*it;
        }
        out<<ss1.str()<<"\n";

        out<<"\t\tAwards & Experience: ";
        for(auto it=student.competitions_experiences.begin();it!=student.competitions_experiences.end();it++)
        {
            out<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<"    ";
        }
        out<<"\n================================================\n";
        return out;
}
istream & operator>>(istream &in, B &student)
{

        cout<<"\nEnter the Student's current CGPA:            ";
        in>>student.current_cgpa;
        string input1,input2;
        cout<<"\nEnter the student's skills. Enter '.' to indicate you are done\n";
        while(input1!=".")
        {
            in>>input1;
            if(input1==".")
                break;
            student.skills.push_back(input1);
        }
        cout<<"\nEnter the student's competitive exam prizes or experiences. Enter '.' to indicate you are done\n";
        cout<<"Write achievements in one line & year (in which it was achieved) in other line\n";
        int year;
        while(input2!=".")
        {
            getline(in>>ws,input2);
            if(input2==".")
                break;
            in>>year;
            student.competitions_experiences.insert(pair<string,int>(input2,year));

       }
        return in;
}


int main()
{

    while(true){
            cout<<"1: Enter Student Details\n2: Enter Student's Resume\n3: Exit\n";
            cout<<"Please select your option: ";
            int n;
            cin>>n;
    switch(n){
        case 1:{
            A s;
            cin>>s;
            cout<<s;
            break;}
        case 2:{
            B s;
            cin>>s;
            cout<<s;
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    }
}

`
```

sample output:

```
1: Enter Student Details
2: Enter Student's Resume
3: Exit
Please select your option: 1
Enter the student's full name:                              sarah niles

Enter the student's date of birth (dd/mm/yyyy):           2/3/2001

Enter the student's age:                                  12

Enter the student's current course he/she is studying in: csa661

Enter the student's roll number (only integers allowed):  4

Enter the student's email id:                             sarah@mail.com

Enter the student's phone no:                             911


                                Student Details
___________________________________________________________________________

                Name:          sarah niles
                Date of Birth: 2/3/2001
                Age:           12
                Course:        csa661
                Roll no:       4
                Phone no:      911
                Email id:      sarah@mail.com

____________________________________________________________________________
1: Enter Student Details
2: Enter Student's Resume
3: Exit
Please select your option: 2

Enter the Student's current CGPA:            8.9

Enter the student's skills. Enter '.' to indicate you are done
c++ java php .

Enter the student's competitive exam prizes or experiences. Enter '.' to indicate you are done
Write achievements in one line & year (in which it was achieved) in other line
sat 1900
2012

olypiad gold
2009

.


                                Student Resume
================================================
                Name:
                Date of Birth:  Age:12
                Email:
                Contact no: 911
                Course Studying in college:
                Current CGPA: 8.9
                Skills: c++ java php
                Awards & Experience: olypiad gold 2009    sat 1900 2012
================================================
1: Enter Student Details
2: Enter Student's Resume
3: Exit
Please select your option: 3

Process returned 1 (0x1)   execution time : 124.751 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Class A has data members of string & integer data type. Yet when class B inherits the protected data members of class A, it only displays int (Contact Number and Age) but not string (Name, Email, DOB).
Why aren't the string data types not displayed (when calling from class B), but integer data types displayed even though both are protected in class A?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) it better.

Comment: Please reduce the code to a [mcve]. Formating and unecessary fluff make this question very hard to read

Comment: The extraction operator, `>>`, should not interact with the user in any way.

Comment: why >> should not interact with the user?

Comment: Consider `std::ifstream in("example.txt"); A a; while (in >> a) ...`. Are those prompts useful or just annoying?

Comment: `istream & operator>>(istream &in, B &student)` never reads the inherited `A` members, so the `int` members are left uninitialized, so you're printing some indeterminate values.

Comment: ... and those members just happen to be stored in the same place as the corresponding members were in the object you used in the previous iteration, but does not exist any more.

Comment: so is there any way to initialize other than istream & operation>>

Answer (score 2):

You're editing two different objects, confusingly both called `s`.

You define `A s;` and `B s`. The second `s` of type `B` has an A sub-object. However, it looks to me like the A sub-object of `B s;` is never initialized.

This might be caused by a confusion between classes and objects. An object is a concrete instantiation of a class. Objects have a lifetime (when they exist) and an address (where they exist), classes exist for the whole duration of your program. With inheritance, classes have base classes, and objects have sub-objects.